# If statement syntax error for beginner

Tags: c++

I'm teaching myself C++ and was writing some code to calculate grade averages with arrays. Everything works except for when I try to display the results. I get the error "expected primary-expression before '<' token" on this line of code.

```
    if(grade1 >= 0 && < 60)
```

followed by a single cout statement and a semi-colon. I looked in the book I am using and on c++ forums. My book looks just like my example and online everyone was missing a semi-colon or something else. Is that my case too?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you pick up a [good book covering C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Change `if(grade1 >= 0 && < 60)` to `if(grade1 >= 0 && grade1 < 60)`

Comment: `if(grade1 >= 0 && grade1 < 60)`

Comment: " My book looks just like my example" - I'm prepared to bet it does not - what book is it?

Comment: @NeilButterworth After reading the examples the book was not what I had, I was just blinded by my firm knowledge that I was right and that the compiler was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include 'grade1' on both comparisons.

```
if (grade1 >= 0 && grade1 < 60)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is this:

```
if(grade1 >= 0 && grade1 < 60)
```

You need to provide a variable for each condition in your `if` statement. The `grade1` variable will not carry over for other comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You must write like this

```
if (grade1 >= 60 && grade1 < 60){ //code here   }
```